# Error while submitting application to Windows Store The native API api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll:OpenEventA() isn’t allowed

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

1028: The native API api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll:OpenEventA() isn’t allowed in assembly AnylyncRuntimeComponent.dll. Update it and then try again.

1028: The native API api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll:CreateEventA() isn’t allowed in assembly AnylyncRuntimeComponent.dll. Update it and then try again.

1028: The native API api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll:CreateEventExA() isn’t allowed in assembly AnylyncRuntimeComponent.dll. Update it and then try again.

Can please help to fix this issue .

Comment: Are you calling OpenEventA, CreateEventA, or CreateEventExA? Those look like legitimate errors: OpenEventA, CreateEventA, and CreateEventExA are not supported in Windows Store or Windows Phone apps. OpenEventW and CreateEventExW are allowed so you can use those instead.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the reply. I have not created any of these in my RuntimeComponent Or in my entire solution.I dont no how to handle this error .can You please suggest me how to handle these type of errors while submitting the build to the store.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build for Unicode -- if your source code calls "OpenEvent" then it is actually replaced by the pre-processor by either the "A" or "W" version depending on whether you're building for ANSI or Unicode.

If you don't use those APIs at all yourself, it means you're linking with someone else's code that wasn't built for Unicode, and you need to ask them to provide you with a Unicode version.